# How to plot every column of data against every other column of data

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matplotlib, file-io

I have a data file of n columns and x number of rows. 
How can I plot every column against every other column of data?

```
data=[]
inFile = open('random.data','r')
    for line in inFile.readlines():
        line = line.split()
        b = np.array([line],dtype=float)
        for i in range(len(b)):
            c=(b[i])
            data.append(c)
inFile.close()
```

This produces an array where I can index each column like so:

```
datax = ([i[0] for i in data])
datay = ([i[1] for i in data])
dataz = ([i[2] for i in data])
dataa = ([i[3] for i in data])
```

and then plot against each other:

```
plt.plot(datax,datay,dataz,dataa,'o')
```

How can I do this using a for loop so that it works for n number of columns?

Comment: You can look at [seaborn's `pairplot` function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html?highlight=pairplot#seaborn.pairplot) but you'll need to get your data in a pandas DataFrame first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `data` in your code above is  pandas df, the below code will work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_data = data
for i in range(len(df_data.columns)):
    for j in range(len(df_data.columns)):
        x = df_data.iloc[:,df_data.index[i]]
        y=  df_data.iloc[:,df_data.index[j]]
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x[i],y[j])
```

To read your data to df, below is the code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('random.data', sep=" ", header=None) #sep depends on your file, it can be space, semicolon or anything.
data.columns = ["a", "b","c", ... "etc.", ...] # Put names of your column in place of a,b,c etc.
```

Comment: Hey Rahul, I'm not sure how to convert it do df either. If you know of any good documentation that would be great.

Comment: @TomRichmond: Updated my answer on how to convert your file to df.

Comment: I also want the plot to work for any number of untitled columns. Can I just replace the data.column with an array created from the number of columns in my file?

Comment: Yes...you can replace with a list of columns

Answer (score 0):

You have `n` columns and I assume you can access each column by `data[]`.

Try this

```
# define n here

numberofplots = math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(2)*math.factorial(n-2))

fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(numberofplots,1, ((i+1)*j)
        ax.plot(data[i], data[j])
```